# Javascript Observer Pattern

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern

I am fairly new to design patterns and I came across [this](https://www.patterns.dev/posts/observer-pattern/) website that explains observer pattern

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";

function logger(data) {
  console.log(`${Date.now()} ${data}`);
}

function toastify(data) {
  toast(data);
}

observable.subscribe(logger);
observable.subscribe(toastify);

export default function App() {
  function handleClick() {
    observable.notify("User clicked button!");
  }

  function handleToggle() {
    observable.notify("User toggled switch!");
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button>Click me!</Button>
      <FormControlLabel control={<Switch />} />
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**My Question:-** I don't understand why do we need to write this extra line `observable.notify("User clicked button!");` inside the `handleClick` function and `observable.notify("User toggled switch!");` inside the `handleToggle` function.

**My Naive Approach:-** We could have simply invoked `logger` function from within the `handleClick` function something like

```
function handleClick(){
return logger('User clicked button')
}
```

I know that `observable.subscribe(logger);` and `observable.subscribe(toastify);` have been used so we need to use the `notify()` method but can't all these be handled using simpple function invokations what's the whole point of using it like this ?

[Sanbox Link from the website](https://codesandbox.io/s/observer-pattern-1-md8k5?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js)

Any example references would much be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is that using observable.notify adds a layer of indirection. So rather than just returning the results of logger(str), you can allow any other part of your app to register for notification, which allows parallel development and increased flexibility/reusability in your JavaScript

Comment: Your code seems to miss the `observable` definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We could have simply invoked `logger` function from within the `handleClick` function...

Yes, but the purpose of the Observer pattern is to **decouple** the publishing code from the subscriber code. The publishing code just knows that it needs to publish the event, and provide the relevant data for the event. It doesn't have any specific knowledge of the subscribers. It's that decoupling that's the point of the pattern.

*(Separately, just as a pragmatic point, if you made that change, you would no longer be calling `toast`. You'd only be calling `logger`.)*

Comment: To call toast we could do the same thing something like function handleToggle(){
return toastify("User toggled switch!")
}  is this wrong ??

Comment: @Sachin - It depends on the level of coupling you're happy with between the code in `App` and the code in `logger`/`toast`. If you're happy to have very tight coupling, you can make the calls directly. But looser coupling is more flexible and, as a result, often more desireable.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use

```
function handleClick(){
    return logger('User clicked button')
}
```

It only replaces the first observer call -- it won't call `toast("User clicked button")`.

The whole point of the Observer pattern is that you can create as many observers as you want, perhaps dynamically, and don't have to code them all in the function that publishes.